# Rails production: locales switching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I've made switching locales with sessions. The logic keeps in controller:

```
class SetLanguageController < ApplicationController

  def russian
    I18n.locale = :ru
    set_session_and_redirect
  end

  def english
    I18n.locale = :en
    set_session_and_redirect
  end

  private

  def set_session_and_redirect
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale
    redirect_to :back
    rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
      redirect_to :root
  end

end
```

switching works with links:

```
link_to_unless I18n.locale == :ru, "Русский", rus_locale_path
link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", eng_locale_path
```

code for locales in routes (unnecessary for question, but if you interesting)

```
get 'rus_locale' => 'set_language#russian'
get 'eng_locale' => 'set_language#english'
```

It works in development perfectly, but on production

application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config','locales', '*.yml').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
```

How can I make it working on production? Thanks

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching in production?  If so, does the cache key contain the locale?

Comment: @PeterGoldstein I'm not understand you clearly I'm afraid. I use default rails `session` method. Can you explain, if I didn't answer your question?

Comment: Read this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html . A typical source of production-only problems is caching, as it's typically disabled in development.  So it's a good place to look.  As your content will be locale dependent, the locale will need to be in the cache_key if you're caching.

Comment: What is not working in production? Is it not switching locale?

Comment: My question should have been a little more clear. Is it throwing any error? How can you tell it is not switching? Is there any caching involved like Peter Goldstein stated?

Comment: @HarshGupta there is no eroor, just default locale is not switching

Comment: Do you have `before_action` in `application_controller` where you set locale using session value?

Comment: @HarshGupta I post the answer with it, but I think it is not well appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with setting a `before_filter` in application controller like

```
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = session[:locale] ? session[:locale] : I18n.default_locale
  end
```

But this solution is dummy because it doesn't solve essence of problem actually - previous code worked in development, but in production. If you know how to fix it more smartly you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

**Robust I18n implementation:**

Add a `locales.rb` initializer to define what `I18n.available_locales` you support:

```rb
# config/initializers/locales.rb

# Permitted locales available for the application
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
```

Set a `language_name` value in each language's locale file (e.g. `fr.yml`):

```yaml
fr:
  language_name: "Français"
```

As you add more languages, this ERB will let you generically switch between them:

```
  // app/views/layouts/_languages.html.erb
  <span class="languages">
   <% I18n.available_locales.each do |locale| %>
      <% if I18n.locale == locale %>
        <%= link_to I18n.t('language_name', locale: locale), url_for( params.clone.permit!.merge(locale: locale, only_path: true ), {style: "display:none" } %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to I18n.t('language_name', locale: locale), url_for( params.clone.permit!.merge(locale: locale, only_path: true ) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
```

For the controller, we automatically find the correct language for the user by detecting their browser's `Accept-Language` HTTP header (using the [http_accept_language](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) gem).

Set a `session` cookie to preserve locale across requests.

Or optionally, use `default_url_options` to insert the `?locale=` param into your app's url.  I do both.

Controller:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = begin
      extract_locale ||
        session[:locale] ||
          http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(I18n.available_locales) ||
            I18n.default_locale
    end
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale
  end

  def extract_locale
    parsed_locale = params[:locale].dup
    I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil
  end

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
end
```